# Why is a map location marked with white circle?

Tags: the-witcher-3

When browsing the world map I noticed this:

[image]

What does the white circle around the location means? Hovering it shows the ordinary details.

Background: I visited the location a while back (both game time and real time) and after not finding the hidden treasure, gave up and forgot about it. (Until seeing it now again. :))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The circle highlight appears once you have been close enough to the place to identify what it is but you haven't yet actually collected all the loot.

The circle disappears and the place appears grey once you have got all the loot.

Comment: Thanks, I know about the place becoming gray, that's the fate of most map markers. :D

Answer (score 4):

That means the objective is somewhere within the circle. Just ride your boat out there and you'll see some chests or barrels that you gotta grab.

Comment: But how come it's not showing for other markers? This is the only marker with a circle as far as I could see in the whole map.

Comment: It only appears like that when you have been close enough to the place to identify what it is but haven't yet got the loot.

Comment: @greg-449 thanks, that's the actual answer to my question. Can you please post it as new answer?

Answer (score 0):

I think the white circle means that, at the particular location with the white circle icon, you will loot an item that ties in to something else, more loot someplace, a quest, etc... the icons without the white circle are just places you go, pick up the loot and that's it.

Comment: Nope, that's not the case. The accepted answer is correct.